# Two jquery datepicker instances in one control ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two text boxes that use the datepicker plugin on the same page.

I use the code below to set attributes for each by using their cssclasses, however the minDate for datepickerLatest does not seem to work on the calendar. It works fine for datepickerEarliest

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEarliestDate" CssClass="datepickerEarliest"></asp:TextBox>
```

```
$(".datepickerEarliest").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '-100:+10',
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '17/08/2012'
    });

    $(".datepickerLatest").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '-100:+10',
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '21/06/2012'
    });
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any issues. Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/wDDxP/